# How to get values from different columns in one row in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have a table with following records, in fig.

[image]

I want the records like this

[image: The cntry_1,cntry_2,cntry_3,cntry_4]

The cntry_1,cntry_2,cntry_3,cntry_4 are according to the country_type_id of first table. country_type_id 1 = column cntry_1

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text (instead of images.)

Comment: Question seems clear and OK to me. I can read text on images, because brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make use of the `PIVOT` to arrive at what you're looking for. You can use it like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT    t.[Business name],
            t.is_default,
            t.is_active,
            t.context,
            t.country,
            t.country_type_id
  FROM      TableName t
) src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Country)
  FOR country_type_id IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) piv
```

See this here ->  http://rextester.com/HUK42854

Hope this helps!!!